# Devise user doesn't sign in even I set up confirm_within parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have an rails app, using devise gem for user authentication.

I used confirmable to send confirmation email to user. It's running well. I got an confirmation email. And I need to confirm my account before successfully signed in.

I would like to let them try our app for a while, before confirm their account. So I setup confirm_within in the devise initializer. It is failed. After user filled in the register form, they will be redirected back to login page after sign up. I checked the log, it seems that the user isn't signed in. So it failed in authentication! before filter.

Here are my configuration.

Model: user.rb

```
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :encryptable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable
```

route.rb

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:password => "passwords"}
```

Initializer: devise.rb

```
  config.confirm_within = 2.days
```

application_controller.rb

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      stored_location_for(resource) || jobs_path
  end
```

jobs_controller.rb

```
  class JobsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!

    ***some functions
  end
```

I am not sure did I missed anything.  Would someone kindly tell me how to fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever actually sign the user in?  You need to make a call of `sign_in @user` in order for the user to get signed in.  Typically you would do this after authenticating the user's credentials when they submit the sign in form...

Comment: Thank for reply @Batkins. The registration and confirmation process is controlled by Devise. I use the official gem and didn't change anything inside. I checked the source code and seems Devise sign_in the user in Registration#create already.... Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry that I can't be of more help, I don't have any experience working with Devise's `confirm_within` feature.  However, [according to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754297/devise-registration-confirmation), it appears that the user is supposed to be signed out after registration because they aren't supposed to be logged in until they confirm their email address by responding to an email, if I'm not mistaken.  If you want them to be logged in automatically after registration then I believe you need to remove the `confirm_within` option.  It sounds to me that the `confirm_within` option is the amount of time the user has in order to confirm that the email address they signed up with is actually theirs (by clicking the link that gets emailed to them).

Comment: according to devise documentation. config_within is a parameter which let user to sign in without confirm their account. thanks so much for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are reading the wrong documentation:
"* +allow_unconfirmed_access_for+: the time you want to allow the user to access his account
#     before confirming it. After this period, user access is denied. You can
#     use this to let your user access some features of your application without
#     confirming the account, but blocking it after a certain period (ie 7 days).
#     By default allow_unconfirmed_access_for is zero, it means users always have to confirm to sign in.
#   * +reconfirmable+: requires any email changes to be confirmed (exactly the same way as
#     initial account confirmation) to be applied. Requires additional unconfirmed_email
#     db field to be set up (t.reconfirmable in migrations). Until confirmed new email is
#     stored in the unconfirmed email column, and copied to email column on successful
#     confirmation.
#   * +confirm_within+: the time before a sent confirmation token becomes invalid.
#     You can use this to force the user to confirm within a set period of time."

in here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb

so for allowing the user to log in without confirmation for a certain time you have to define:

```
config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for
```

and to allow the user to confirm, which after he cant confirm anymore which means he needs a new confirmation to be sent for that email because the token becomes invalid is:

```
config.confirm_within
```

hope it was explicit.

Comment: actually config.confirm_within was the old name of config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for, sorry I didnt see how old was this post